# Determine the number of times a List Item has been viewed

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, auditing

I want a report that displays how many times a list **item** has been viewed. I tried to obtain this information from Audit Log Reports but the exported Excel file does not appear to give this information. The columns available are:
Site Id, Item Id, Item Type ... 
Under Item ID I have a list of GUIDs with either a Document or List Item Type. I can see several different List ones.

I know a list item has an ID but does it also have an actual GUID? 
How can I find what the GUID is of the item so I can cross reference to the report?

Users access the list item by:

```
http://sharesite/SitePages/NewsDialog.aspx?IDA=21&IsDlg=1
```

UPDATE: output of Rest (removed body tag to save space)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://share.lifecapnet.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:etag="W/&quot;8&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://share.lifecapnet.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/StrategicNews(21)</id>
  <title type="text">New Life Capital team making connections at first offsite</title>
  <updated>2016-02-04T12:15:36Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="StrategicNewsItem" href="StrategicNews(21)" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/TextPosition" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="TextPosition" href="StrategicNews(21)/TextPosition" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/BngImage" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="BngImage" href="StrategicNews(21)/BngImage" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="StrategicNews(21)/CreatedBy" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="StrategicNews(21)/ModifiedBy" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments" href="StrategicNews(21)/Attachments" />
  <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.StrategicNewsItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:ContentTypeID>0x01009E2B3766E4C83B4BB6BBF56C1751719A</d:ContentTypeID>
      <d:Title>New Life Capital team making connections at first offsite</d:Title>
      <d:ApproverComments m:null="true" />
      <d:Intro>Video now available</d:Intro>

      <d:NewsRelease m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-01-22T00:00:00</d:NewsRelease>
      <d:NewsExpire m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-02-12T00:00:00</d:NewsExpire>
      <d:TextPositionValue>Bottom</d:TextPositionValue>
      <d:BngImageId m:type="Edm.Int32">52</d:BngImageId>
      <d:ApprovalStatus>0</d:ApprovalStatus>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">21</d:Id>
      <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
      <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-02-04T12:15:36</d:Modified>
      <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-01-22T09:58:39</d:Created>
      <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">184</d:CreatedById>
      <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">184</d:ModifiedById>
      <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">8</d:Owshiddenversion>
      <d:Version>2.0</d:Version>
      <d:Path>/Lists/StrategicNews</d:Path>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a list item has both an `ID` (integer: 1, 2, 3...)  and a `UniqueId` (a GUID).
You can get the `UniqueId` of a given item you know the `ID` of with **PowerShell**:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://<URL>
$list = $web.Lists["<ListName>"]
$item = $list.GetItemById(<Integer_ID>)
$item.UniqueId
```

You can get the same all client-side by requesting the REST API:

**Client-side (SP2013)**:

```
http://sharesite/_api/lists/getbytitle('Site pages')/items/getbyid(21)?$select=UniqueId
```

**Client-side (SP2010), for document libraries**:
Get the `m:etag` value from:

```
http://sharesite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Sitepages(21)
```

**Client-side (SP2010), for lists**:
Use the following JavaScript. You can simply copy/paste it in the address bar of Internet Explorer (mind the `javascript` prefix that me be dropped when you paste it) (and be sure to first navigate to a page of the target site):

```
javascript:var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); var item = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Strategic News').getItemById(21);ctx.load(item);ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){alert(item.get_item('UniqueId'));},null);
```

**EDIT**
OK, now that we've found all that, as per your comments, it looks like getting the `UniqueId` of the item was not what you needed to get view reports.
To get what you want (i.e. views of a given page with a given query string param), the best would be to parse IIS logs. IIS logs contain all information (datetime, client IP, authentified user if any, page URL, request string...) you need here. Just remind they reside on all servers of the farm, so you'll have to get them from all servers to have a complete report. Here are some toools to parse IIS logs:

- [Log Parser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659): free command-line tool
- [Log Parser Lizard](http://www.lizard-labs.com/log_parser_lizard.aspx): a visual layer for Log Parser
- [Examples of Log Parser requests for SharePoint](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=85)

Comment: I don't have access to powershell, any other options?

Comment: Edited my answer to add client-side options.

Comment: I've typed in the SP2010 version and I get the xml for the list item but cant see the guid for the item in xml. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does. Don't you find the `<link m:etag` node in the XML file? As I mentioned, it's the one containing the `UniqueId` for the item.

Comment: Updated question with REST output, could you kindly look. thanks

Comment: Hum, indeed you're missing the `etag` node I was mentioning. Will look at that and come back to you.

Comment: OK, the difference is: I was testing on a document library, not a simple list. I'll try to find a way to get the `UniqueId` for a simple list item in SP2010...

Comment: Did not find it with a pure REST request. Seems impossible in SP2010 for lists. So, fallback with JavaScript code that you can paste into the address bar of IE. Updated my answer with this.

Comment: I managed to get the Guid of the item with JavaScript, however the guid does not match any Item Id of the Audit Log report. This cant be right as I'm sure users would have read the item.. Audit log is switched on to log read of list items. Am I looking at wrong place?

Comment: I'm quite sure the GUID you have in the audit report _is_ the `UniqueId` you now managed to get. Are you sure your visitors read the item with its display page? What's "NewsDialog.aspx"? Is it Something custom?

Comment: The link on the home page points to a custom page (NewsDialog.aspx) and the ID is passed to the page. Custom page has a ListViewWebpart which gets the news item from the list and filtered by the ID.

Comment: OK: I think if the item is only displayed in a view, and no in its complete display form, it does not count as a "view" in the audit logs.

Comment: Is it possible to see logs of pages with a url parameter NewsDialog.aspx?id=21 using SharePoint or IIS log files

Comment: Yup, my recommendation would be to parse IIS logs. IIS logs contain everything you need. I'm updating my answer to include détails on that.